# Probability that the numbers of a die appear with the same frequency

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, dice

> Let's assume we throw a die $n$-times. What is the probability that all numbers appear with the same frequency if $n\to\infty$?

**My approach:**

Let be $P(A_n)$ the probability that each number appears $k$ times after $n$ throws. It's easy to see that $P(A_n)=\frac{n!}{(k!)^6 6^n}$ if $n\mod 6=0$ and $P(A_n)=0$ otherwise.
The problem is to check the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)$. We only have to consider those $n$ with $n\mod 6=0$.

We know by Stirling approximation that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}~n^ne^{-n}}=1$. Also
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}~n^ne^{-n}}{\left(\sqrt{2\pi k}~k^ke^{-k}\right)^6}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 6k}~(6k)^{6k}e^{-6k}}{8\pi^3 k^3~k^{6k}e^{-6k}}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 6k}}{8\pi^3 k^3}6^{6k}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 6k}}{8\pi^3 k^3}6^{n}\\
&\text{and } \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 6k}}{8\pi^3 k^3}=0.
\end{align*}
Keeping this in mind we conclude:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{n!}{(k!)^6 6^n} \underset{=1}{\underbrace{\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}~n^ne^{-n}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}~n^ne^{-n}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi k}~k^ke^{-k}}{\sqrt{2\pi k}~k^ke^{-k}}\right)^6}}=\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}~n^ne^{-n}} \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}~n^ne^{-n}}{(\sqrt{2\pi k}~k^ke^{-k})^6}\frac{(\sqrt{2\pi k}~k^ke^{-k})^6}{(k!)^6}\frac{1}{6^n}\\
&=\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}~n^ne^{-n}} \frac{(\sqrt{2\pi k}~k^ke^{-k})^6}{(k!)^6}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 6k}}{8\pi^3 k^3}\frac{6^n}{6^n}.
\end{align*}
If we apply the Stirling approximation and the above limit we see that for all $n$ with $n\mod 6=0$ we have:
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}~n^ne^{-n}} \frac{(\sqrt{2\pi k}~k^ke^{-k})^6}{(k!)^6}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi 6k}}{8\pi^3 k^3}=1\cdot1\cdot 0=0.
$$
(Note that $n\to\infty\implies k\to\infty$).

---

Is this correct? It seems a bit counterintuitive because I thought if one extends the stochastic experiment to infinite die throws each number must appear with the same frequency as the die is assumed to be fair. So my first guess was that the probability should be $1$?!

Comment: With *exactly* the same frequency?  No.  With *nearly the same frequency*, yes.  It is not that the distance between amounts of $1$'s rolled and $2$'s rolled approaches zero, it is that the *relative distance* between amounts of $1$'s rolled and $2$'s rolled approaches zero.  That is, letting $A_n$ be the number of ones rolled after $n$ rolls, and $B_n$ the number of twos rolled after $n$ rolls... it is not that $|A_n-B_n|\to 0$ it is that $\frac{|A_n-B_n|}{n}\to 0$.

Comment: "Same frequency" is just ridiculously vague in a limit context.

Comment: @Paul, how should the question be phrased instead to make it more precise?

Comment: @Paul I disagree.  I see nothing ambiguous in : "Let $P(A_n)$ be the probability that each number appears k times after n throws."  Normally, there is ambiguity about whether the original poster intends (for example) at least $k$ or exactly $k$.  Here, the interpretation of at least $k$ isn't really suggested, especially, given the formula that the original poster gave for $P(A_n)$.

Comment: I don't think it's vague -- it seems like a perfectly well-formulated problem, that I believe Philipp has both correctly interpreted and correctly found the limiting answer to be $0$. The vague version of this problem would be something like "What is the probably that all numbers appear with *approximately* the same frequency," which couldn't be answered without some notion how much tolerance should be allowed.

Comment: As for some more straightforward intuition about why this result is reasonable, flip $2n$ coins. As $n \to \infty$, the probability that exactly $1/2$ of the coins are heads approaches $0$, but the probability that the proportion of heads is in $[\frac 1 2 - \epsilon, \frac 1 2 + \epsilon]$ approaches $1$.